# Forward Declare instance of Template Class with Virtual Functions

Tags: c++, templates, forward-declaration

I have created a template class `A<T>` in `mynamespace` which I need to forward declare to use in class `B` in `mynamespace2`.  Is it possible to forward declare a specific instance of `A` for use in `B`, namely `A<int>`?

**File: a.h**

```
#include "b.h"

namespace mynamespace{    
    template <class T>
    class A{
        A(T);                                // constructor
        mynamespace2::B* b_attribute;
    };    
}
```

**File: b.h**

```c++
/* How to forward declare A<int>? This doesn't work:
 *
 *  namespace mynamespace{
 *     class A<int>;
 *  }
 * 
 * neither does this:
 *
 * namespace mynamespace{
 *     template <class T>
 *     class A<T>
 * }
 */

namespace mynamespace2{    
    class B{
        B();
        mynamespace::A<int>* a_attribute;    // for use over here
        virtual void f(A<int>*);             // note: virtual function
    };    
}
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no different than forward-declaring anything else, except that you have to get the namespace right:

```
namespace mynamespace{    
    template <class T> class A;
}
```

`A` is declared in `mynamespace`, so you have to specify it, as such.

If you really want to avoid explicitly specifying the namespace every time, add a `using` declaration:

```
namespace mynamespace2{
    using mynamespace::A;

    class B{
        B();
        A<int>* a_attribute;    // for use over here
    };    
}
```

Once a `using` declaration is made, you can just refer to `A` anywhere within `mynamespace2`.

Note that you must still forward-declare the template in the other namespace, before pulling it in with `using`.

Comment: I don't see any difference between the OP and your use of `A` within `B` (without the using directive).

Comment: Is it possible to specifically forward-declare `A<int>` and not `A<T>`? I wish to implement a virtual function in class `B` which takes `A<int>*` as an argument and virtual functions doesn't allow for template syntax.

Comment: @LukeCollins Virtual functions cannot BE templates, but they certainly can USE templates. So `virtual void f(A<int>*);` would be just fine. What you can't do is `template <class T> virtual void f(A<T>*);`.

Comment: The OP edited the question, after I pointed out the incorrect usage of the namespace reference.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yes thanks for that, I added the `namespace::` stuff later cause I forgot to.

Comment: That's ok, I simply removed that part.

Comment: I keep getting the error `specializing member ‘mynamespace::A<int>::func’ requires ‘template<>’ syntax
 void A<int>::func(mynamespace2::B *b){` because in class `A`, I have implemented a function which uses a `B` pointer.

Comment: Note a using directive in namespace scope can have unpleasant and confusing effects. I wouldn't recommend it unless `mynamespace` is on the small side, and you have strict control over `mynamespace` and anything that might ever be added there in the future.

Comment: The shown code in my answer compiles without issue with gcc 8. If you're getting a compilation error, it must be from some different code, and it's unlikely that anyone can help you with an error from compiling code that's not even shown.

Comment: @LukeCollins That might be time for a brand new question. The solution depends on whether you want `A<int>::func` to use the same code as the general `A<T>::func` or to do something special when `T=int`.

Comment: And before posting a new question, you should review the requirements for a [mcve], as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help].

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks, I'll ask a new question.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Added a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50078871/forward-declaration-of-template-class-visitor-design-pattern) :)