# Forward Declaration of Template Class (Visitor Design Pattern)

Tags: c++, templates, forward-declaration, visitor-pattern

I am trying to forward declare a templated class `A<T>` for use in a class `Visitor`. It would suffice for my purposes to declare the `int` instance `A<int>` of the class `A`. I have tried two approaches but both give different errors, and I don't know how to proceed.

Here is a MWE of my error:

```c++
namespace visitor{  
    class Visitor{
    public:
        virtual void visit(nsp::A<int>*) = 0;
    };    
}

namespace nsp{    
    template <class T>
    class A{
        A();
        T t_attribute;          
        void accept(visitor::Visitor*);
    };    

    void A<int>::accept(visitor::Visitor*){
        v -> visit(this);
    }        
}

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

You can try running the code [here](http://cpp.sh/7vzxt) to see the error I get:

```
error: specializing member 'nsp::A<int>::accept' requires 'template<>' syntax
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: It should be `template<> void A<int>::accept(`, just like error message suggests.

Comment: The defintion must macht the declaration. So use `template <class T> void A::accept(visitor::Visitor*){...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are mixing things here, you should declare accept method as:

```
template<class T>
void A<T>::accept(visitor::Visitor* v){
    v -> visit(this);
}
```

as class A is template. Then you can specialize for any type.

Comment: You are right, this seems to solve the problem for my MWE, but when I am trying to apply this to my project I get the error "undefined reference to '`A<int>::accept(visitor::Visitor*)`'"

Comment: I seem to be getting an [error similar to this](http://cpp.sh/4u2q5). Any ideas why I get an error?

Comment: @LukeCollins your online example does not define `A::A()`, so the error is quite expected.